# How can I make recursion works correctly in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to code a Mastermind game with Ruby. It's an exercise from https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/ruby-mastermind.

I build a method #make-guess that loops  4 times taking input from the user and validating it i.e making sure that the input is included in #BALL array.

For that, I declared a condition if the input is included in the #BALL array, append it to an array #guess, and else, call the function again (recursion).

The problem is when an input is not included, the function #make-guess loops more than 4 times.
Here is the code I'm working on:

```
class MasterMind
  BALLS = ['r', 'g', 'o', 'y', 'v', 'm']

  comp_selection = BALLS.sample(4)

  def make_guess
    guess = []
    until guess.length == 4
      puts "Guess the computer's combination from: 'r', 'g', 'o', 'y', 'v', 'm'"
      value = gets.chomp
      if BALLS.include?(value)
        guess.append(value)
      else
        puts 'Selection not in the combination, try again'
        make_guess
      end
    end
    guess
  end

end

master = MasterMind.new
puts master.make_guess
```

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Rails, in which case you should remove all of the Rails tags. Also, `comp_selection = BALLS.sample(4)` is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion here. (at least where you used it)

```rb
class MasterMind
  BALLS = ['r', 'g', 'o', 'y', 'v', 'm']

  comp_selection = BALLS.sample(4)

  def make_guess
    guess = []
    until guess.length == 4
      puts "Guess the computer's combination from: 'r', 'g', 'o', 'y', 'v', 'm'"
      value = gets.chomp
      if BALLS.include?(value)
        guess.append(value)
      else
        puts 'Selection not in the combination, try again'
        # Remove this line to fix your problem.
        # make_guess
      end
    end
    guess
  end

end

master = MasterMind.new
puts master.make_guess
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question. However, my program requires four inputs from the user, and if they make an incorrect selection, no input will be provided as the 'else' statement only serves to display an error message. To ensure proper user input, I require the 'else' statement to notify the user of the incorrect selection and provide an additional prompt for correct input.

Comment: Did you try the code? With this code, the program will loop until the user makes four _valid_ inputs.